# Advances in Indistinguishability Obfuscation

Tags: io

I [hear](https://www.quantamagazine.org/computer-scientists-achieve-crown-jewel-of-cryptography-20201110/) there's a recent advance in [Indistinguishability Obfuscation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44770/what-is-indistinguishability-obfuscation), aka [io](/questions/tagged/io), with emphasis on Aayush Jain, Huijia Li and Amit Sahai [*Indistinguishability Obfuscation from Well-Founded Assumptions*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1003.pdf) ([eprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1003) and [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09317), August 2020).

For the applied cryptographer inexperienced in Indistinguishability Obfuscation, what's the big picture? What concrete problem does this aim to solve, preferably with orders of magnitude of the data and work required?

Comment: @kelalaka: what linked answer? All answers in the linked question are old.

Comment: The usage requirements don't change much. The first answer gives a need for the sofware developer. and the [floor cat's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/46794/18298), too.

Comment: Do you mean the big picture of how their io actually works, or what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @Nic: ideally I'd like both! But I'd want at least to know what it can do, perhaps with an example of a concrete class of algorithms that it can obfuscate.

Comment: As the title suggests, the construction in the Jain-Li-Sahai paper is the first that is based on "standard" long-studied assumptions. The paper was a culmination of a long series of works that aimed at achieving this.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer: ah. So the advance would be mostly about the confidence we can have in the security, not in the kind or size of problems that can be addressed? I had hoped that with a new path to IO would come practical advances, and hopefully some understandable application. Perhaps I should have weighted more "far from ready to be deployed", and less "enables the creation of “deniable” encryption (…) and “functional” encryption" in the magazine article.

Comment: "So the advance would be mostly about the confidence we can have in the security, not in the kind or size of problems that can be addressed." Yes I suppose: the goal here is full-blown obfuscation (i.e., for all circuits) from standard assumptions. We already knew how to do obfuscation for some simpler tasks (e.g., [point functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/001)) from "standard" assumptions, but it is not clear if these functions have any useful applications. But we should wait for someone more knowledgeable in the area to verify this.

Answer (score 3):

Indistinguishability obfuscation allows programs to run while they remain encrypted, including their internal data structures.  This allows for a lot of things; just one example is programs can generate their own signing key so any computational process that we currently rely on a central authority for (e.g. verified software builds) we can now entrust to a computer program.

However, the recent advance is purely theoretical and we are still a long way away from implementing efficient IO. [Wikipedia » Indistinguishability obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indistinguishability_obfuscation):

> There have been attempts to implement and benchmark IO candidates. For example, as of 2017, an obfuscation of the function $x_1 ∧ x_2 ∧ ⋯ ∧ x_{32}$ at a security level of 80 bits took 23.5 minutes to produce and measured 11.6 GB, with an evaluation time of 77 ms. Additionally, an obfuscation of the Advanced Encryption Standard encryption circuit at a security level of 128 bits would measure 18 PB and have an evaluation time of about 272 years.

---

*Pellet--Mary, Alice (26 May 2020). "[Co6GC: Program Obfuscation | COSIC](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/blog/program-obfuscation/)". [www.esat.kuleuven.be](http://www.esat.kuleuven.be). Archived from the original on 11 November 2020. Retrieved 22 August 2021.*